# Weebhooks handlers how to handle different events by different webhookhandlers

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, webhooks

Following situation:
I can provide a webhook for a 3rd party provider and this provider will send all the events to this webhook receiver.

I created a standard WebHookHanler

```
public class CustomHandler : WebHookHandler
{
    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext context)
    {
        //todo: handling logic
        return Task.FromResult(true); 
    }
}
```

This provider sends all the events to this webhook, so I have to first parse the message to know what event it is to handle it correctly (so ie. write a method for each event)
My question is: is there a way I can write specific handler per specific event, and the event will be routed to the proper handler?

Because in a current situation everything comes to that 1 handler and parsing the message to get the event does not seem to be very elegant here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This partially answers my question: https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/issues/237

If you write several handlers, there is no way only one of them is called. It will proceed to execute every handler anyway, but you can exit from any unnecessary handler checking ie. ID property (as in provided URL)

Problem is my provider sends everything to the same URL always, so I don't even have possibility to modify the id part in the request

Maybe that helps somebody